# VS 2017 adding code incorrectly

Tags: vb.net

I am working with VS 2017 - using VB.Net, my project will get damaged. When I review I see that there a several places where code in being inserted in the wrong places - the following code was placed after the final  tag.

When I delete it, it will be regenerated over and over. Any help would be appreciated.

`</root>adata name="MenuStrip1.TrayLocation" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    <value>134, 17</value>
  </metadata>
</root>`

Comment: Is this inserted into `*.vbproj` after the `</Project>` tag? Note: This seems to be the contents of a resx-file.

Comment: It is a `.resx` file, which should end with `</root>`. The additional garbage at the end starts with `adata name=...`. Anyway, `adata` seems like the end of `metadata` (which is closed out with `</metadata>`). Yup, certainly something is corrupting the file.

Comment: It happens to both the vbproj and resx files - different code segments though. Do you think reinstalling VS 2017 would help?

Comment: I don't think it could hurt. What if you close the project, put the complete metadata tag before closing root, then reopen?

Comment: I ended up moving the project from a NAS drive to my local. So far the problem has not happened. Thanks for all the help.